# Hi, I need to add the library address (0x.. exc.) of the url below.. Where can I find It?

Tags: addresses, openzeppelin, library

I need to add the library address (0x.. exc.)  of the following url .. Where can I find It?

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Comment: Welcome to the community, Rebisproject. Are you trying to verify a contract on Etherscan? We need some context to your question to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You dont, just flatten your code (meaning instead of using 'import' statements, just copy and paste the library you want to use before your contract)